# Send images when app is tombstoned/closed?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, background

The app I'm currently developing needs to send images and text to a webservice, and so far so good. The app works fine, but the next step is to make it keep sending when the user exits the app or changes to another app.

How do I achieve this?

I've looked at the background agent function, but that doesn't seem to be what I want. I do not want to wait every 30 minutes and then try to send for 25 sec with the periodic agent, and the users will almost never be in the very limiting state that the resource-intensive agent requires (over 90% battery life, must be on wi-fi etc).

Am I missing something obvious here? Only sending pictures and text when the user has the app active is a big down side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it is not possible to do what you require with the current WP7 OS. The Windows Phone 7 OS has been designed to restrict applications in such as way that the user's security is protected, battery life is prolonged and they have a consistent experience. Allowing any application to execute arbitrary code in the background, without imposing constraints on execution time or duration would allow people to write applications that are extremely resource intensive. This is not good for the end user!

The "periodic" or "resource-intensive" agents, [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28VS.92%29.aspx), are your only options.

Comment: Thats a real bummer. But if that's what MS wants, we'll have to do it in another way. An idea would be to show users on a live tile that stuff needs to be sent, and they'll have to open the app and let it.